# How do I construct an arbitrary text summary in TensorFlow?

Tags: logging, tensorflow, tensorboard

I want to log some arbitrary strings in TensorBoard.

I know how to do it for arbitrary scalars:

```
from tensorflow.core.framework import summary_pb2
value = summary_pb2.Summary.Value(tag='Accuracy', simple_value=0.95)
my_summary = summary_pb2.Summary(value=[value])

summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter()
summary_writer.add_summary(summary)
```

But how to do the same thing but for **arbitrary text summary**?
Something like (which doesn't exist):

```
value = summary_pb2.Summary.Text(tag='MyTag', str='Arbitrary text come here')
```

**UPD:** Note that I provided an example how to create an arbitrary scalar summary without calling `session.run(...)`. I want to be able to do it for **text** as well.

Comment: Also checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54821986) for a one/two line method using `tensorboard.summary.text_pb()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have been searching for an answer, too. Peeking at some source code for TensorFlow/Board, I found a way which seems to work (I don't know whether a simpler solution exists).

```
value = "Random text"
text_tensor = tf.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=tf.string)
meta = tf.SummaryMetadata()
meta.plugin_data.plugin_name = "text"
summary = tf.Summary()
summary.value.add(tag="whatever", metadata=meta, tensor=text_tensor)
summary_writer.add_summary(summary)
```

Comment: this does not show up on my tensorboard for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

You have to make use of [tf.summary.text](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/text) module. Check this simple example below:

```
summary_op1 = tf.summary.text('tag1', tf.convert_to_tensor('Tag1: Random Text 1'))
summary_op2 = tf.summary.text('tag2', tf.convert_to_tensor('Tag2: Random Text 2'))
summary_op3 = tf.summary.text('tag3', tf.convert_to_tensor('Tag3: Random Text 3'))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./Tensorboard', sess.graph)
    for index, summary_op in enumerate([summary_op1, summary_op2, summary_op3]):
        text = sess.run(summary_op)
        summary_writer.add_summary(text, index)
summary_writer.close()
```

You will be getting an output something like this in Tensorboard:

[image]

Hope this answer helps you.

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. I want to create an arbitrary text summary without calling `session.run(...)`. See how I did it for a scalar value.