# How to manually create text summaries in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

First of all, I already know *how to manually add float or image summaries*. I can construct a `tf.Summary` protobuf manually. But what about text summaries? I look at the definition for summary protobuf [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/core/framework/summary.proto), but I don't find a "string" value option there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TensorBoard's text plugin offers a `pb` method that lets you create text summaries outside of a TensorFlow environment. 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/tensorboard/plugins/text/summary.py#L74

Example usage:

```
import tensorboard as tb
text_summary_proto = tb.summary.pb('fooTag', 'text data')
```

Answer (score 1):

John Hoffman's answer is great, though the `tb.summary.pb` API seems not available as of TF 1.x. You can instead use the following APIs:

```
tb.summary.text_pb("key", "content of the text data")
```

Just FYI, `tb.summary` has many similar methods for other types of summary as well:

```
'audio', audio_pb',
'custom_scalar', 'custom_scalar_pb',
'histogram', 'histogram_pb',
'image', 'image_pb',
'pr_curve', 'pr_curve_pb',
'pr_curve_raw_data_op',
'pr_curve_raw_data_pb',
'pr_curve_streaming_op',
'scalar', 'scalar_pb',
'text', 'text_pb'
```

Comment: This method appends `/test_summary` to whatever tag you pass to the function. Make sure to change the tag to what you want using `text_summary.value[0].tag='my/tag'`